# Can a non-angel become one by stealing an angel's Grace?

Tags: supernatural

Later on in *Supernatural*,

> Castiel loses his Grace and therefore becomes human. He regains his angel status by stealing the Grace of another angel.

Could a human, demon, or other creature kill an angel and steal the angel's Grace, and thus become an angel?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's possible. Remember Castiel's human vessel is actually a guy called Jimmy Novak. Yet when Castiel loses his grace, he does not turn into Jimmy Novak. He's still Castiel. Powerless and mortal, but still not entirely human.

That said, I wouldn't rule it out for a future episode. They'll pretty much try anything in that show these days.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I should point out that there's a good chance that "Jimmy" doesn't exist any more. After all Cas has put that body through (Including dying at least twice, possibly three times), we have no way of knowing whether the human soul that used to be Jimmy is still hanging on. Regardless, +1 for noting that they'll probably try this eventually. After making Dean a demon, turning Sam into an angel is the logical next step

Answer (score 2):

Grace is simply a source of power, equivalent to a human soul. Since Castiel has a "borrowed" Grace it's being used up and it is unable to renew itself.

So if a human somehow obtained a Grace and was able to absorb it, they would have angel level power for awhile. However it's more likely that a human attempting to absorb a Grace would simply fry themselves with an overload of energy. Viewing an angel's true form is enough to burn a human's eyes out, I can't imagine what actually absorbing an angel's source of power would do.

Answer (score 2):

#### No. If it were possible to steal the [Grace](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Grace) of an Angel and use if for freely by anyone without specific knowledge or specific capacity, there would be a black market in Grace as Angels were captured by demons and drained for their Grace.

> Grace is a type of divine energy related to an angel's being. It's effectively what makes them angels; without it they are mortal. Anna calls its power "pure creation." Removal of grace is considered a great taboo by angels; it is akin to disobeying orders and punishable by a death sentence, or in the very least torture and imprisonment. Uriel is able to take Anna's grace from the oak tree that it created when she fell. In turn she is able to re-imbibe it and return her angel status.

- Angelic power is so great, it would not make sense for demons to NOT harvest Grace from every Angel they come across, rather than stabbing them with Angel blades and moving on. Since the manipulation of Grace appears to be a knowledge unique to Angels, it is not likely such a power could be used by just anyone.

> Anna Milton reveals that she is an angel who chose to fall from Heaven and ripped out her grace painfully. Witnesses mistook Anna's grace for a shooting star. Where it landed, in Union, Kentucky, an enormous oak tree sprouted in the space of a year. In conversation with Dean, Anna indicates that given the choice she would not recover her grace, and would remain human. She relishes the full range of emotions that humans enjoy and the choices they have.

- Angels can remove their own Grace forcefully when they fall. It is presumed they can also remove the Grace of other Angels, but it appears to be something not easily done because Angels kill other Angels with alarming frequency during the series, denoting the absorption of Grace is difficult, at best.

> Metatron takes Castiel's grace from him to use in a spell to cast all the angels from Heaven. Without it, Castiel is human, although much like Anna he was still able to hear the angels on "angel radio." After living as a human for some time, he kills an angel called Theo and takes in his grace, and becomes an angel again. It therefore appears that grace is not unique to an individual angel, and can be transferred, though Castiel seemed quite unsure whether taking Theo's grace would be permanent, or what powers he would have. The consequences of stealing another angel's grace was later revealed by Metatron, who told Castiel that his stolen grace was fading, and that once it was used up, Castiel would burn out along with it.

- Angels losing their Grace don't revert to their Human hosts. They remain their angelic selves just without power. Grace acts like the fuel Angels use for their powers. But it appears to be a fuel uniquely able to be used by other Angels. However, use of that power is temporary. An Angel who loses their Grace and absorbs the Grace of another can temporarily boost their powers but will burn out and die when they run out of borrowed Grace.

> When angels leave their vessels a small amount of the angel's grace remains inside the vessel. Angel Lore says that "the departed shall remain, and the remains shall be the departed."[5]The Men of Letters believed that if the grace could be extracted, it could be used in a tracking spell to locate the angel the grace belonged to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible for a non-angel to steal power from an angel by consuming their Grace. As pointed out above, however, the Grace does not naturally replenish itself so one would have to actually contain an angel for harvesting long-term. Season 13 spoilers follow:

> Asmodeus steals Gabriel's Grace and gains his shapeshifting abilities.

Answer (score 0):

Well I wouldn't say one could become an angel by stealing an angels power, however I should point out that Anna became human when she fell. She also became an angel again when she recovered her Grace (the same as Castiel did after Metatron stole his Grace). So I would say, no one cannot become an angel by stealing the angels Grace. Because said person would just burn through the Grace until it is used up or the Grace would destroy said human or demon. However it does raise an interesting question as both Anna and Castiel became human after they lost their Grace, so why can the other way (human becoming angel) not be so? 
So I would say that it's possible for a human to become an angel, but only if God gave him/her specifically Grace, tuned to the person given it. But since God doesn't really want to interfere anymore the chances of that seem unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

I say that if an angel steals another's grace it will fade out and die
but in humans, they can be angels permanently, however if they cut their grace,
they will die and the grace falls off.

Comment: Is there evidence of this in the show?

Answer (score 0):

As we see in "Game Night", when grace in injected into a human, it is almost like a poison that slowly kills whoever it is in. A human does not become an angel if they consume grace but instead, they will die and live among them in heaven. Or hell. You never know in *Supernatural*.